# Gray color model not working

Tags: color

I am unable to set text color using the Gray color model from the `xcolor` package. The M(NW)E below results in an "Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)" error:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\textcolor[Gray]{10}{text}

\end{document}
```

Does anybody know how to use the Gray color model appropriately?

Comment: It is clearly a bug. \convertcolorspec{Gray}{10}{gray}\tempcolor gives the wrong syntax. Report it to the author.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Can you please write an answer?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat writing that it is a bug it not an answer, and I don't have the time to track the code to find a fix (and even if I had the time, I don't know if it is worth to spend it for this as one can use gray instead).

Comment: I have already emailed the package author in the hope that he will do something about it. If not, oh well, I guess it's not *that* big of a deal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually hyperref (or more precisely hycolor/xcolor-patch.sty) contains a patch for this

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\textcolor[Gray]{10}{text}
abc
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the `gray` name in lower case and 0.1 instead of 10 (if you mean percent)

See here : https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors

This should work:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt,svgnames]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\textcolor[gray]{0.1}{text}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I want to use the uppercase `Gray` model though, not the lowercase `gray` model.

Comment: I added the link there because this model is not present in `xcolor`

Comment: It is though; check out page 10: http://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/xcolor.pdf

Comment: @TheRiddler .. yes just found there ...

Comment: So it doesn't work?

Comment: Seems that in the manual is only the way to convert... but not to use directly