# Discrepancy between stated and observed parameter range of color models from xcolor

Tags: color

I have noticed that the stated parameter range ([page 10](http://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/xcolor.pdf)) for some of the color models in `xcolor` does not in general correspond to the range of parameters that you are actually allowed to type in without receiving an error message. Also, for all the "integer" models you are allowed to type in decimal numbers (except for HTML), which in effect makes them decimal models. I have listed all of these discrepancies below:

- **hsb**

  - Stated:

    - h ∈ [0, 1], h ∈ **R**
    - s ∈ [0, 1], s ∈ **R**
    - b ∈ [0, 1], b ∈ **R**
  - Actual:

    - h ∈ [-0.16666557312, 1.16666557312], h ∈ **R**
    - s ∈ [-163.8399879455, 163.839988708496093749], s ∈ **R**
    - b ∈ [-163.8400001525, 1638.400001525878906249], b ∈ **R**
- **Hsb**

  - Stated:

    - H ∈ [0, 360], H ∈ **R**
    - s ∈ [0, 1], s ∈ **R**
    - b ∈ [0, 1], b ∈ **R**
  - Actual:

    - H ∈ [-59.999397277832031249, 419.999397277832031249], H ∈ **R**
    - s ∈ [-163.8399879455, 163.839988708496093749], s ∈ **R**
    - b ∈ [-163.8400001525, 1638.400001525878906249], b ∈ **R**
- **tHsb**

  - Stated:

    - H ∈ [0, 360], H ∈ **R**
    - s ∈ [0, 1], s ∈ **R**
    - b ∈ [0, 1], b ∈ **R**
  - Actual:

    - H ∈ [-119.998786926269531249, 360.999992370605468749], H ∈ **R**
    - s ∈ [-163.8399879455, 163.839988708496093749], s ∈ **R**
    - b ∈ [-163.8400001525, 1638.400001525878906249], b ∈ **R**
- **RGB**

  - Stated:

    - R ∈ [0, 255], R ∈ **Z**
    - G ∈ [0, 255], G ∈ **Z**
    - B ∈ [0, 255], B ∈ **Z**
  - Actual:

    - R ∈ [-0.003883361816406249, 255.003883361816406249], R ∈ **R**
    - G ∈ [-0.003883361816406249, 255.003883361816406249], G ∈ **R**
    - B ∈ [-0.003883361816406249, 255.003883361816406249], B ∈ **R**
- **HSB**

  - Stated:

    - H ∈ [0, 240], H ∈ **Z**
    - S ∈ [0, 240], S ∈ **Z**
    - B ∈ [0, 240], B ∈ **Z**
  - Actual:

    - H ∈ [-39.999595642089843749, 279.999595642089843749], H ∈ **R**
    - S ∈ [-16383.999992370605468749, 16383.999992370605468749], S ∈ **R**
    - B ∈ [-16383.999992370605468749, 16383.999992370605468749], B ∈ **R**
- **Gray**

  - Stated:

    - G ∈ [0, 15], G ∈ **Z**
  - Actual:

    - G ∈ ∅
  - Special Note: See my previous [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/515766/gray-color-model-not-working) on this matter.
- **wave**

  - Stated:

    - λ ∈ [363, 814], λ ∈ **R**
  - Actual:

    - λ ∈ [-16383.999992370605468749, 16383.999992370605468749], λ ∈ **R**
  - Special Note: To be fair, the `xcolor` documentation does specify a broadened parameter range for the `wave` color model at the bottom of page 10. This range is: λ ∈ [-16383.99998, 16383.99998] which is still not quite what is actually observed.

**Does anybody have an explanation for some or all of these discrepancies?**

An MWE is shown below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\framebox{hsb}

%hsb upper bounds
\textcolor[hsb]{1.16666557312, 163.839988708496093749, 1638.400001525878906249}{text}

%hsb lower bounds
\textcolor[hsb]{-0.16666557312, -163.8399879455, -163.8400001525}{text}

\hspace{0pt}\\

\framebox{Hsb}

%Hsb upper bounds
\textcolor[Hsb]{419.999397277832031249, 163.839988708496093749, 1638.400001525878906249}{text}

%Hsb lower bounds
\textcolor[Hsb]{-59.999397277832031249, -163.8399879455, -163.8400001525}{text}

\hspace{0pt}\\

\framebox{tHsb}

%tHsb upper bounds
\textcolor[tHsb]{360.999992370605468749, 163.839988708496093749, 1638.400001525878906249}{text}

%tHsb lower bounds
\textcolor[tHsb]{-119.998786926269531249, -163.8399879455, -163.8400001525}{text}

\hspace{0pt}\\

\framebox{RGB}

%RGB upper bounds
\textcolor[RGB]{255.003883361816406249, 255.003883361816406249, 255.003883361816406249}{text}

%RGB lower bounds
\textcolor[RGB]{-0.003883361816406249, -0.003883361816406249, -0.003883361816406249}{text}

\hspace{0pt}\\

\framebox{HSB}

%HSB upper bounds
\textcolor[HSB]{279.999595642089843749, 16383.999992370605468749, 16383.999992370605468749}{text}

%HSB lower bounds
\textcolor[HSB]{-39.999595642089843749, -16383.999992370605468749, -16383.999992370605468749}{text}

\hspace{0pt}\\

\framebox{wave}

%wave upper bound
\textcolor[wave]{16383.999992370605468749}{text}

%wave lower bound
\textcolor[wave]{-16383.999992370605468749}{text}

\end{document}
```

Comment: why confuse the test file with `\hspace{0pt}\\ ` which just generates warnings?  But in general error checking in the middle of a tex calculation is hard, if you go out of documented range and it doesn't give an error but overflows or underflows or gives a spurious result or accidentally gives a sensible result then it is what it is.